# "An error occurred while loading the archive" when extracting Kali Linux.7z on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, zip, kali, 7zip

I'm downloading Kali Linux 2016.1 for Virtual Box, which only had a torrented .7z file available, but I'm not able to extract it with Archive manager or p7zip.

After installing `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full` I tried these two commands:

```
7za e  Kali-Linux-2016.1-vbox-i686.7z
7za x  Kali-Linux-2016.1-vbox-i686.7z
```

The error I get is:

```
error: there is no such archive
```

The path of the file is `Home/Downloads/Kali-Linux-2016.1-vbox-i686/Kali-Linux-2016.1-vbox-i686.7z`

Comment: and does that file actually exist?  Where did you save it? That error suggests there is simply no file of that name. Please [edit] your question and give us the full path to the archive and the output of `ls -l` on it.

Comment: @terdon I added the path, not sure what the ls -l is... Sorry I'm new with this sort of thing.

Comment: `ls` is a terminal command that will list files. Without other arguments it lists those in the current directory. It's a way to reassure that the a file exists where you expect it to exist. May I suggest however, that you use Archive Manager instead of terminal programs if you don't know how to use them? The former actually uses the latter any way so for a simple archive extraction there's no advantage. If the extraction didn't work there should be a pop-up window with an error message. What exactly did you do to try to extract the archive with Archive Manager?

Answer (score 1):

When you run a terminal command giving it a file as input, the file must exist. If the file is in your current directory, it is enough to give the file name (`command file`). If, however, the file is in another directory, you need to give its path (`command /path/to/file`).

In your case, you have saved the archive in `$HOME/Downloads/Kali-Linux-2016.1-vbox-i686/Kali-Linux-2016.1-vbox-i686.7z`, so you need to do one of:

1. Use the file's path

   ```
   7za e  $HOME/Downloads/Kali-Linux-2016.1-vbox-i686/Kali-Linux-2016.1-vbox-i686.7z
   ```
2. Move into the directory before running the command:

   ```
   cd $HOME/Downloads/Kali-Linux-2016.1-vbox-i686/
   7za e Kali-Linux-2016.1-vbox-i686.7z
   ```